# Session return an empty response in other functions using Codeigniter 3.1

Tags: php, codeigniter

This code is working fine only in this function but when i get session in other functions then it return an empty response.

```
$id = '123'; 
$this->session->set_userdata('id','$id');
$get_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
print_r($get_id);
```

Get data in other function like.

```
 $get_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
 print_r($get_id);
```

which is return an empty response.

If anyone has any suggestions it would be very much apppreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nearly, try this.

```
$id = array( '123' ); <-------
$this->session->set_userdata( 'id', $id ); <--------
$get_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
print_r($get_id);
```